# datagridview form load

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'd love to know why this code puts the value 5 in the columns cells

```
 For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Me.datagridADRORD.Rows
        row.Cells("Historical Diff").Value = 5
    Next
```

But this code doesn't work, ie the cell is left blank. There are values in the formulas cells so there should be a value to put in the calculated column

```
 For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Me.datagridADRORD.Rows
        row.Cells("Historical Diff").Value = row.Cells("ADR Price").Value - row.Cells("ORD Price").Value
    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try Cell index, instead of Cell Name.

//1 is cell index

```
row.Cells(1).Value = 5
```

Comment: hard coding the value works fine even with the column name, the formula doesn't, that's the question

Comment: Ok sorry. For formula, convert decimal or integer. Integer.Parse("23"); or Decimal.Parse("23.20")